# I can't compile/install TP-Link T4u v3 drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, wifi, usb-device, compiler

I am a real begginer in Linux and don't know why, I can't install my USB WiFi card drivers, I always get errors. I searched all of the Internet and tried over 10 solutions but nothing worked for me. Now my /usr/src folder is empty!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please edit your post to include the relevant steps you performed, and show us at which step you ran into problems (including the last command you typed on the console and the resulting error message)? Otherwise it is _really_ difficult to understand the problem and point you in the right direction ...

Answer (score 0):

I am make changes for this driver. get it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihgE4mDeQkoQC8RBZwAiDQQ8knIZ0UzO/view?usp=sharing